# Trying to understand the timeline section in chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

I am trying to use chrome DevTools to check out the loading and rendering sequence of my page.

I watched a video where the timeline had a records section with the events that happaned layed out in a very clear column [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxD9A.png). Yet I cannot seem to find this view in my browser.

Has the timeline section in chrome DevTools changed? And if so then where can I see a clear view of the events such as in the view I was trying to find.

Thanks.